# Missing words in NLTK vocabulary - Python

Tags: python, nltk

I was testing the [NLTK package](http://www.nltk.org/)'s vocabulary. I used the following code and was hoping to see all `True`.

```
import nltk

english_vocab = set(w.lower() for w in nltk.corpus.words.words())

print ('answered' in english_vocab)
print ('unanswered' in english_vocab)
print ('altered' in english_vocab)
print ('alter' in english_vocab)
print ('looks' in english_vocab)
print ('look' in english_vocab)
```

But my results are as follows, so many words are missing, or rather some forms of the word are missing? Am I missing something?

```
False
True
False
True
False
True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the corpus is not an exhaustive list of all the english words, but rather a collection of texts. A more appropriate way of telling if a word is a valid english word is to use wordnet:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

print wn.synsets('answered')
# [Synset('answer.v.01'), Synset('answer.v.02'), Synset('answer.v.03'), Synset('answer.v.04'), Synset('answer.v.05'), Synset('answer.v.06'), Synset('suffice.v.01'), Synset('answer.v.08'), Synset('answer.v.09'), Synset('answer.v.10')]

print wn.synsets('unanswered')
# [Synset('unanswered.s.01')]

print wn.synsets('notaword')
# []
```

Answer (score 2):

[NLTK corpora](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html) do not actually store every word, they are defined as "a large body of text".

For example, you were using the `words` corpus, and we can check its definition by using its `readme()` method:

```
>>> print(nltk.corpus.words.readme())
Wordlists

en: English, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix)
en-basic: 850 English words: C.K. Ogden in The ABC of Basic English (1932)
```

Unix's words is not exhaustive, so it may indeed be missing some words. Corpora are, by their nature, incomplete (hence the emphasis on natural language).

That being said, you might want to try using a corpus that is derived from a dictionary, like `brown`:

```
>>> print(nltk.corpus.brown.readme())
BROWN CORPUS

A Standard Corpus of Present-Day Edited American English, for use with Digital Computers.

by W. N. Francis and H. Kucera (1964)
Department of Linguistics, Brown University
Providence, Rhode Island, USA

Revised 1971, Revised and Amplified 1979

http://www.hit.uib.no/icame/brown/bcm.html

Distributed with the permission of the copyright holder, redistribution permitted.
```